# QTableView, conditional row selection in ExtendedSelection mode

Tags: row, selection, qtableview, selectionchanged

I use QTableView in ExtendedSelection mode with SelectItems behavior.
I would like to implement the following behavior:
1) When only one cell is selected - do nothing
2) When more than one cell is selected - select full row for each selected cell.

Here is an example:

```
void BaseTableView::selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &selected, const QItemSelection &deselected)
{   
    QTableView::selectionChanged(selected, deselected);
    QItemSelection currentSelection = selectionModel()->selection();

    //table has selection 
    if(!currentSelection.isEmpty())
    {
        QItemSelectionRange selectionRange = currentSelection.first();

        //select whole row if more than one cell is selected
        if(currentSelection.count() > 1 || selectionRange.height() > 1 || selectionRange.width() > 1)
        {
            if(!deselected.isEmpty())
                selectionModel()->select(deselected, QItemSelectionModel::Deselect | QItemSelectionModel::Rows);
            if(!selected.isEmpty())
                selectionModel()->select(currentSelection, QItemSelectionModel::Select | QItemSelectionModel::Rows);
        }
    }
}
```

This code somehow works. But I can't find a better solution.
Problems:
1) Blinking of selection when mouse is used. Probably due to double call of `selectionChanged` or something like this.
2) Selection with Shift key does not work as it should. When selection area with shift key pressed is changed `deselected` is always empty. So selection is always increases.

what is a better solution to implement described behavior?
How to fix selection with a pressed `Shift` key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution.

I reimplemented `select()` method of `QItemSelectionModel`. Than it's enough to do some check and add `Rows` flag to the initial flag.